# ¿Como mostrar en un label el nombre de un Id que pertenece a otra tabla?

Tags: c#, sql

```
 public bool LoginBD(string usuario, string pass)
        {
            using (var conexion = ObtenerConexion())
            {
                conexion.Open();
                using (var SqlComando = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    SqlComando.Connection = conexion;
                     SqlComando.CommandText = "SELECT * from TablaUsuario INNER JOIN Posicion ON TablaUsuario.IdPosUsuario = Posicion.IdPosicion WHERE UsuarioLogin=@usuarioLogin and PassW=@pass";

                    SqlComando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usuarioLogin", usuario);  
                    SqlComando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
                    SqlComando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    SqlDataReader reader = SqlComando.ExecuteReader();

                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            UsuarioLoginCache.IdUsuario = reader.GetInt32(0);
                            UsuarioLoginCache.UsuarioLogin = reader.GetString(1);
                            UsuarioLoginCache.Password = reader.GetString(2);
                            UsuarioLoginCache.Nombre = reader.GetString(3);
                            UsuarioLoginCache.Apellido = reader.GetString(4);
                            UsuarioLoginCache.Posicion = reader.GetInt32(5);
                            UsuarioLoginCache.Email = reader.GetString(6);                  
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

Tengo este código para iniciar sesión y al entrar en el `formulario menú`, muestro en un `label` cada dato que extraigo con el `reader`, el cual cada dato guardo en `variables estáticas`, pero en el `UsuarioLoginCache.Posicion = reader.GetInt32(5);` guardo es un `Id` que va dirigido a otra tabla, por lo tanto en el `label` se me muestra es el Id. ¿como hago para que a partir de ese Id me muestre es el nombre de la posición asociada a el? Utilizo `C#` y `Sql-Server`

Comment: Te faltaria hacer un join con la tabla que tiene los datos de ese ID

Comment: @RamiroBarone y en el reader como lo traigo?

Comment: Tal cual lo haces, pero hacele el join en la consulta y si no te hace falta, no traigas todos los datos, para optimizar la consulta.

Comment: @RamiroBarone edite la pregunta, pero sigue mostrandome el nuero

Comment: @Nathy y en que posicion de tu reader quedo el dato que vos queres?

Comment: Al hacer select * trajiste todos los campos de todas las tablas...

Comment: @gbianchi en la tabla Posicion esta el nombre de la posicion que quiero mostrar

Comment: reader.Getstring (o GetInt o Getloquesea) lleva como parametro el nombre o posicion del campo que estas buscando.. cual es el campo que tiene lo que queres mostrar? eso es lo que tenes que poner... entendes lo que hace reader.GetString???

Comment: @gbianchi el campo esta en otra tabla

Comment: Eso no importa. Te recomendaria leer sobre joins en sql... el resultado es una sola tabla con todos los campos que pusiste en el select.. proba tu query en un manejador de base de datos, y vas a ver que tenes las columnas de las dos tablas. Antes de solo copiar la respuesta que te dieron, entende el porque es la respuesta...

Comment: yo he usado join pero datagrid, nunca los he usado en label, igualmente gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asi deberias realizar la consulta y luego llamar en el reader. No deberias traer todos los campos de ser necesario ya que consume recursos, transmision de datos, etc. y No deberias guardar el pass. Si necesitas mas campos agregalos a la consulta y al reader. Es un ejemplo mas corto sobre tus campos.

1-Segun el orden de los campos que devuelve tu consulta, es como los debes leer en el reader. En tu select en SQL comenzas con p.Posicion como primer campo para mostrar en el resultado, seria el orden 0 en reader de SqlDataReader que creaste.

```
    public bool LoginBD(string usuario, string pass)
    {
        using (var conexion = ObtenerConexion())
        {
            conexion.Open();
            using (var SqlComando = new SqlCommand())
            {
                SqlComando.Connection = conexion;
                 SqlComando.CommandText = "SELECT p.Posicion, u.Nombre, u. Apellido, u.Email, from TablaUsuario u, Posicion p INNER JOIN Posicion ON u.IdPosUsuario = p.IdPosicion WHERE u.UsuarioLogin=@usuarioLogin and u.PassW=@pass";

                SqlComando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usuarioLogin", usuario);  
                SqlComando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
                SqlComando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                SqlDataReader reader = SqlComando.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        UsuarioLoginCache.Posicion = reader.GetString(0);
                        UsuarioLoginCache.Nombre = reader.GetString(1);
                        UsuarioLoginCache.Apellido = reader.GetString(2);
                        UsuarioLoginCache.Email = reader.GetString(3);                  
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

2-Luego esa informacion que tenes guardada se la asignas a tu label.

```
Label1.Text = UsuarioLoginCache.Posicion;
```

Comment: The multi-part identifier "TablaUsuario.IdPosUsuario" could not be bound.'
Me salio ese error

Comment: me faltaron los alias en el where.

Comment: y ese join esta mal.. va  a hacer un producto cartesiano.. mejor explicarle (aparte del tema de todos los campos) que viene en un reader y como se leen los campos de un reader...

Comment: Perdon, di por entendio que sabia como leer un Reader, ya que lo hacia en su pregunta, y el join no lo analice debido a que no era ese su problema sino traer otro campo de otra tabla.

Comment: @RamiroBarone gracias por la respuesta, ya entendi lo que quisieron decir ambos